# Using sklearn-python model in spark ML 2.2.0 for prediction

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a **text classification problem** in **python** using **sklearn**. I have created the model and saved it in a **pickle**.

Below is the code I used in sklearn.

```
vectorizerPipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=True,
        stop_words='english')),
('classification', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='hinge'))),])

prd=vectorizerPipe.fit(features_used,labels_used])

f = open(file_path, 'wb')
pickle.dump(prd, f)
```

Is there any way to use this same pickle to get the output in DataFrame based apache  spark and not RDD based. I have gone through the following articles but didn't find a proper way to implement.

1. [what-is-the-recommended-way-to-distribute-a-scikit-learn-classifier-in-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672114/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-distribute-a-scikit-learn-classifier-in-spark)
2. [how-to-do-prediction-with-sklearn-model-inside-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887621/how-to-do-prediction-with-sklearn-model-inside-spark)
   -> I found both these questions on StackOverflow and find it useful.

[deploy-a-python-model-more-efficiently-over-spark](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-python-model-more-efficiently-over-spark-497fc03e0a8d)

I am a beginner in Machine learning. So, pardon me If the explanation is naive. Any related example or implementation would be helpful.

Comment: were you able to find any solution on how to use scikit-learn trained model on spark clusters?

Comment: @Rudr : No, we have created a separate model using scala for that particular process.

Answer (score 0):

RDD -> spark dataframe using Spark

like:

```
import spark.implicits._
val testDF = rdd.map {line=>
                      (line._1,line._2)
                     }.toDF("col1","col2")
```